# Is it possible to install Active Directory on a machine that already has sharepoint installed?

Tags: active-directory

All the links I've read say the correct way is to have Active Directory installed before Sharepoint. But currently I have a machine running sharepoint and need to install active directory on it, is it possible? Has anyone done it? Any tips or links?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to have a guess here and say yes it can work if you install Active Directory without enabling Domain Controller, so if you don't change SharePoint's server domain, it won't affect SharePoint. If it's a virtual machine you can just have a snapshot and try it and see what happens.

(That's just a guess, never tried it out. If am wrong please, someone correct me).

Comment: I'll try it with and without and report back

Comment: if you try it "with", it's going to join SharePoint's server on a new domain, it will break things, it's like migrating SharePoint's environment to new domain. But without I guess won't affect anything. Let me know what happens!

Comment: Using the standard installation wizard and following this guide http://www.howtogeek.com/99323/installing-active-directory-on-server-2008-r2/ then since the sharepoint is on the same machine as the DNS and AD I went and configured an Alternate Access Mapping (which seemed to remove all the ones that were configured before the AD was  installed, I don't mind that for now) to point port 90 of sharepoint to this own machine, now on the other machines in the network all I had to do was change the Domain of the computers and changed the DNS to point to the new DNS inside the AD+Sharepoint machine.